# How can i repeat a while cicle in php?

Tags: php, html, loops, while-loop

I need to create a 'wall' of images.
There's my code:

```
 <?php 
          $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wall");
          $q->execute();
        
          
          while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  ?>
           
      <div class="col-4-perc"><img src="<?=$site?>/assets/img/wall/<?=$row['source']?>.png" 
       alt="Foto wall" class="img-fluid"></div>

    <?php } ?>
```

I would like to repeat the while loop repeating the photos in the database at least 3/4 times but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you have stored 3/4 images in database?

Comment: Use `fetchAll()` to get all the rows into an array instead of `fetch` inside a loop, and then loop through the array as many times as you want to.

Comment: No, i have 39 photos but the 'wall' must be 100/120 photos.
I need to repeat the 39 photos which I am extracting with this query many times

Comment: dropsnoot thanks, great method, I had to think about it first

Comment: Collect the results to reuse.. querying again is superfluous.

Comment: Instead of writing multiple while or foreach loops after each other, I would go with a `for` loop then. You can let that run from 0 to 99 directly, and then access the elements in your array "repeatedly", by clamping down the loop counter variable to the actual index range inside your array, using the modulo operator and the `count` of your array elements ... https://3v4l.org/NsaRf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained  in the comments, you have to use `FetchAll` instead of `fetch` in a while. Here is a example script for the result you want:

```php
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wall");
$q->execute();
$allImage = $q->fetchAll() ;
$limit = 100 ;
$activeKey = 0 ;

for ($i = 0; $i < $limit ;$i++){
    
    if (!isset($allImage[$activeKey]['source'])) {
        $activeKey = 0 ;
        // if the line does not exist, reset to the first key (0)
    }

        echo "<div class='col-4-perc'><img src='{$site}/assets/img/wall/{$allImage[$activeKey]['source']}.png' 
       alt='Foto wall' class='img-fluid'></div>";
        $activeKey++ ;
    
}
```

Images are saved in `$allImage`, a table with numeric indexes. Next we just have to loop with a simple for using `$limit` (the max image you want display).
And `$activeKey` for the curent displayed image, if `$allImage[$activeKey]` is not set, reset to `0`.

Comment: I have already managed to solve the problem, but your answer is excellent